# FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() returns null even in managed bean thread

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, jboss-eap-6, facescontext

I have a fairly standard archirecture where a `PrimeFaces` page calls a login action in a class annotated with `javax.inject.@Named` and `javax.enterprise.context.@SessionScoped`.

The `doLogin()` method receives null back from `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` even though the Faces Servlet *should* be properly invoked.

Answer (score 1):

There are many posts that say essentially, "the only time `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` will return null is when it's called outside a managed bean thread". But I did find one post on another forum that identified a build/class loader issue that causes it. Somehow, due to improperly specified dependencies, your `FacesContext` class can get loaded for the container and again for the app. So what is supposed to be a singleton turns into two singletons (somehow...?). Anyway, I'm posting this to record the fix, not to fully explain the problem behind the symptom.

I'm using `JBoss Developer Studio`, building with `Maven` for `JBoss EAP 6.2`. `EAP` comes with modules for `JSF 1` and `JSF 2.1`. I want to use 2.1, which is stored here:

```
C:\JBoss\jboss-eap-6.2.0\modules\system\layers\base\javax\faces\api\main.
```

In my `EJB` project `POM` I had incorrectly added a dependency for `jsf-api` `<scope>compile`, which resulted in `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returning `null` as described above.

The solution was: in the `POM` for my `ejb` and my `web` projects, I added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

And to make sure my deployed `ejb` project also tells `JBoss` about that I needed to make sure it gets published with this in it's `MANIFEST.MF`:

```
Dependencies: javax.faces.api:main
```

That can be done by `Maven` too, by putting an archive configuration in the `POM` for the `ejb` project where the build plugin was created:

```
<!-- most of this <build> element was already in my POM -->
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                <!-- I added this <archive> element to tell Maven to add the dependency line in MANIFEST.MF -->
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>javax.faces.api:main</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

For me, the `maven-ejb-plugin` entry was already there and I just added the archive definition to the existing `<configuration>`. I assume if you are building with ejb-jar-plugin or ejb-war-plugin, the same `<archive>...</archive>` definition could be used.